# jQuery getJson no response when searching solr

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, solr, getjson

I am trying to search a local Solr core and am getting no response using getJSON. I know the URL works and returns a response but the getJson function seems to return null.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ray Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    Document ID:<br>
    <input id="query" type="text" name="document_ID"><br>
    <button onclick="searchSolr();">Search</button>
    <div id="results">
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function searchSolr() {
        var searchStr = $('#query').val();
        if (searchStr.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        var searchURL = "http://localhost:8983/solr/Ray-Docs/select?q=*&wt=json&json.wrf=on_data";
        $.getJSON(searchURL, function (result) {
            var docs = result.response.docs;

            var total = 'Found ' + result.response.numFound + ' results';
            $('#results').prepend('<div>' + total + '</div>');
        });
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try invoking getJSON like below?

```
jQuery.getJSON(sourceURL).done(function(returnData){
  //Data Processing
});
```